# fputc leaves the first line empty before inserting text

Tags: c++, file

I use getchar() and loop to get a text and use fputc() to put into the text file, but it always leaves the first line empty in the text file after writing. The loop stops when character input is a dot (.). How can I delete the first line?

Updated (12/29/2016): I used DevC++ and the codes run finely without creating an empty blank, but my VisualStudio2015 had the problem.

Example: create a file named test.txt

input: this is a text.

output: (in the text file)

> [ a blank line ]
>
> this is a text

```
void writeFile(char *fileName){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(fileName, "wt"); //write text
    if (fp == NULL) {
        cout << "Failed to open" << endl;
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else {
        int i = 0;
        char c = '\0';        
        cout << "Enter a text and end with dot (.): ";
        fflush(stdin);
        //c = getchar();
        while (c != '.') {
            fputc(c, fp);
            c = getchar();
        }
        cout << "Written successfully" << endl;
        fclose(fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reversing the order of the fputc() and getchar() lines.

Comment: The `fflush(stdin)` does not flush the input stream, it is meant for output streams.  Try `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: Why are you using both C++ streams (`cin`, `cout`) and C style streams (`FILE *`)?  *Don't cross the streams.*  Use `std::ifstream` for files.

Comment: FYI, when using I/O prefer to write and read as many characters per transaction.  The `fputc` will be slower to write 128 characters than an `fwrite` or `fputs`.

Comment: I was trying to use different methods to write into the text file, I used std::ifstream to work on the exercise then I encountered the problem. Thank you for your advice and useful tips :D.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, is there a reason for the C functions? Doing something like this in C++ would be better suited to using streams, like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void writeFile(const char *fileName)
{
    ofstream writeToFile;
    writeToFile.open(fileName);
    if (!writeToFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Failed to open" << endl;
        return;
    } else {
        string stringToWrite{""};
        char c = '\0';        
        cout << "Enter a text and end with dot (.): ";
        while (c != '.') {
            std::cin >> c;
            stringToWrite += c;
        }
        writeToFile << stringToWrite << endl;
        cout << "Written successfully" << endl;
        writeToFile.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char *fileName="test.txt";
    writeFile(fileName);
    return 0;
}
```

or, alternatively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void writeFile(const char *fileName)
{
    ofstream writeToFile;
    writeToFile.open(fileName);
    if (!writeToFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Failed to open" << endl;
        return;
    } else {
        string stringToWrite{""};     
        cout << "Enter text and press return: ";
        getline(cin, stringToWrite);
        writeToFile << stringToWrite << endl;
        cout << "Written successfully" << endl;
        writeToFile.close();
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char *fileName="test.txt";
    writeFile(fileName);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ?? define "better suited".

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It is better to write idiomatic C++ for a C++ compiler.

Comment: The compiler doesn't care. *People* Do (sometimes).

Comment: Thanks for the pedantry. It contributed a lot to the question.

Comment: Well yes it is a bit odd here, but the main reason was I wanted to try some C methods that one of my friend asked me to do. And thank you for you your codes.

Answer (score 0):

c is 0 on the first pass, hence the blank line.

change the while loop to

```
  while( (c = getchar()) != EOF)
   {
       if(c == '.')
         break;
   }
```

It looks a bit odd, but is idiomatic for reading characters from a stream in C.

Comment: Umm I just added information on my post about different IDE giving different results. I have the problem only on VisualStudio2015, and I did try modifying my why loop as your suggestion but It still did not work.